# Probability that next flip is tails, given $P(p ≤ z) = z^4$ + last five flips were tails

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function

Bob gives Alice a weighted coin that lands on tails with some probability $p$. Specifically $P(p \le z) = z^4$.

Alice flips the coin 5 times, and every time it lands tails.

Find the probability that Alice's next flip is also tails.

---

My attempt (not sure if this is right):

$E[p] = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F_{Z}) dz = \int_{0}^{1} (1-z^4) dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} (1-1)dz = [z-\frac{z^5}{5}]^{1}_0 = 0.8.$

Answer (score 1):

You have found the expected value of the *prior* probability of tails before any data were observed.

$f_Z(z)=4z^3$

But after $X = 5$ tails after $n = 5$ flips, Alice has more information about $z$.

From Bayes' theorem:

$f_{Z|X}(z)=\frac{\text{Binom(X;n,z)}f_Z(z)}{\int_0^1\text{Binom(X;n,z)}f_Z(z)dz}=9z^8$

$E[f_{Z|X}(z)]=\int_0^1zf_{Z|X}(z)dz=0.9$

We can check the result with a quick simulation in R:

```
set.seed(2136226507)
z <- runif(1e7)^(1/4)
mean(z) # prior mean
#> [1] 0.8000725
mean(z[rbinom(1e7, 5, z) == 5L]) # posterior mean
#> [1] 0.9000232
```